# SQLAlchemy: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_expire_attributes' on bulk_update_mappings

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to get use of the SQLAlchemy ORM's `bulk_update_mappings` method, but I'm getting a most unhelpful error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/strategies/tests/test_collectors.py", line 173, in test_collect__with_update
    provider.collect()
  File "/vagrant/strategies/models.py", line 46, in collect
    self.collector.update()
  File "/vagrant/strategies/database/collectors.py", line 60, in update
    db_session.bulk_save_objects(strategies)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 150, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2203, in bulk_save_objects
    return_defaults, update_changed_only)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2340, in _bulk_save_mappings
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2332, in _bulk_save_mappings
    isstates, update_changed_only)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 121, in _bulk_update
    bookkeeping=False)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 705, in _emit_update_statements
    value_params)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 998, in _postfetch
    state._expire_attributes(state.dict,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_expire_attributes'
```

The same error also happens when I use `bulk_save_objects`, but oddly not on `bulk_insert_mappings`, which seems to be indicating that there is some issue with my updates, but the documentation is not very helpful. My guess is that it has something to do with relationships, but I've tried using both the full relationship objects and just their `id`s for update values, and no luck so far.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, it turns out it was actually a bug, and zzzeek has resolved it as can be seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3525/on-bulk-update-the-state-is-discarded-at).

Answer (score -1):

So, I found out that `bulk_save_objects` doesn't work well with some other ORM features, namely [`load_only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only). This is the part of the code that was causing trouble:

```
new_data_dict = get_me_the_data_blah_blah()
existing = db_session.query(Stuff).filter_by(visible=True).options(load_only('id', 'some_unique_field'))
                                                           # THIS: ^^^^^^^^^
existing = {s.some_unique_field: s for s in existing.all()}
new = []
for d in new_data_dict:
    item = existing.get(d['some_unique_field'])
    if item is not None:
        for field, value in d.items():
            setattr(item, field, value)
    else:
        item = Strategy(provider=self.provider, **d)
    new.append(item)
db_session.bulk_save_objects(new)
db_session.commit()
```

So, with `load_only` (which remained from the original implementation, which used `Session.add_all`) some of the values were never referenced and therefore never loaded, so the bulk methods saw them as `None`.

Therefore, removing `load_only` resolves the issue:

```
new_data_dict = get_me_the_data_blah_blah()
existing = db_session.query(Stuff).filter_by(visible=True)
existing = {s.some_unique_field: s for s in existing.all()}
new = []
for d in new_data_dict:
    item = existing.get(d['some_unique_field'])
    if item is not None:
        for field, value in d.items():
            setattr(item, field, value)
    else:
        item = Strategy(provider=self.provider, **d)
    new.append(item)
db_session.bulk_save_objects(new)
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: this is not the answer, this should not fail.  Can you please respond to the bug report at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3525/on-bulk-update-the-state-is-discarded-at and add more detail?  thanks.